# How to send data to service when the application crash and close

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with Xamarin.iOS. Now I want to send some data(such as the type of device and the version of system). I add the code in method `public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)`but it doesn't work. If I use the same code in `public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)` it works fine.However ,i just call the method when the application crash or close.Anyone can help me?

Comment: You might want to look at using a commercial crash reporter... Microsoft has one (and it is free): App Center : https://appcenter.ms/sign-in?original_url=%2Fapps

Comment: Thanks for advance.But i think it is just a simple issue that doesn't need to use some SDK.

Comment: NP, just remember when the app is "crashing", WillTerminate is not called during a "crash", but when the OS is performing an *orderly* shutdown of that app/process.... you are not going to be able to reliably make any network calls let alone do anything else, crash reporters write to a log file that is transmitted after the app is restarted....

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you are right. I will try to use the APP Center.